# How to use AWS Translate "TranslateText" API via POSTMAN

Tags: postman, amazon-translate

I am building a POC using AWS Translate and one of the requirement is to use REST API.

I have constructed the below url :

[image]

but when I hit the url using POSTMAN I get the below error :

```
{
    "__type": "UnknownOperationException"
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have managed to find a fix to my issue. The issue was that, I was expecting the "**x-amz-target**" header to have a friendly name e.g "**translate**" but from this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/translate/latest/dg/examples-sigv4.html), the "**x-amz-target**" header needs to be "**AWSShineFrontendService_20170701.TranslateText**"

**Solution:**

1. In postman, I created a new POST request.
2. I then changed the URL specific to an AWS Translate region from:

   ```
   https://translate.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/TranslateText
   ```

to :

```
    https://translate.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/
```

3. Under "Headers" I added the following headers:

   **Content-Type: application/x-amz-json-1.1**
   **X-Amz-Target: AWSShineFrontendService_20170701.TranslateText**
4. Under "Body", I selected "raw", and added the following sample body:

   ```
   {
     "SourceLanguageCode": "en",
     "TargetLanguageCode": "fr",
     "Text": "Creating a test terminology in AWS Translate"
   }
   ```

After testing again I got it working, as you can see in the screenshot below :

[image: AWS_Translate_POSTMAN]

Comment: Link above is dead; AWS has same info here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/translate/latest/dg/examples-sigv4.html , eg:

# POST requests use a content type header. For Amazon Translate,
# the content is JSON.
content_type = 'application/x-amz-json-1.1'
amz_target = 'AWSShineFrontendService_20170701.TranslateText'

Comment: I'll update dead like shortly ...